# deltaspike integrating @ConversationGroup?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, seam3, codi, deltaspike

Recently I have been trying and testing deltaspike in my leisure times. it says it integrated codi and seam 3. but how come i dont see @conversationGroup in it?

any clue anyone?

thanks

Comment: Maybe you should bring this up on the user's group?

Comment: if you dont mind, could you explain or help me to do it?

Comment: They still have it on their list. We searched for an alternative and found http://os890.blogspot.com/2013/07/add-on-codi-scopes-for-deltaspike.html

Comment: @DarWhi the problem is that library uses a different type of conversation, which does not even come with a conversation id. also the way it starts and ends is very different, and you will end up confusing yourself.

Comment: That's not correct. That lib is 1:1 (c&p with small changes for DeltaSpike) what you have in CODI since years. The cid you know from std. conversations is the Window-ID there and every conversation within the window has an implicit (optionally explicit) type-safe group. The most important reason why they created it is the different handling which is way more aligned with other JSF-Scopes, more flexible and not badly broken as the std. CDI conversations.